C# Generic with both notnull and nullable fields
I need a class for a regular tree in the whole project. Sometimes the tree is used with a string key and sometimes with a Guid key.
This class should have not null Id and nullable ParentId.

If i use this class:

public class TreeNode<TKey> 
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TKey? ParentId { get; set; }
}

1.a. TKey = Guid. I have an error "CS0037: Cannot convert null to 'type' because it is a non-nullable value type" when try assign null value to parentId.
1.b. TKey = string. There's nothing wrong with the string key.

If i add where TKey: struct:

public class TreeNode<TKey> where TKey : struct
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TKey? ParentId { get; set; }
}

2.a. TKey = Guid. There's nothing error.
2.b. TKey = string. I have an error "CS0453: The type 'Type Name' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'Parameter Name' in the generic type or method 'Generic Identifier'".
How do I modify the class so that both types of key can be used?
Edited:
Thanks for answers. Thought maybe there's some lifehack. I decided to choice 2 class with base:
public class NamedEntry<TKey> 
{
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TreeNode<TKey> : NamedEntry<TKey> where TKey : struct
{
    public TKey? ParentId { get; set; }
}

public class TreeNodeNullable<TKey> : NamedEntry<TKey> where TKey : class
{
    public TKey? ParentId { get; set; }
}


One option might be to use TKey = Guid? instead of Guid, in which case your first option will compile and run; however, it might be better to rethink the design.

it's impossible to do, because string is a reference type and GUID is a value type. They don't play well together when specifying constraints on generic parameters. Not to mention that nullable value types are very different than nullable reference types in almost every regard but the c# representation.

Wouldn't where TKey : IConvertible work? or may be IComparable?

The main issue is that Guid is a value type and string is a reference type.
Having a generic parameter of either value or reference type does not give us a lot of room to maneuver when it comes to creatively applying constraints to it (docs).
The solution I can give you is to declare a struct generic type that encapsulates a reference type such as this:
public struct StructOf<TClass>
where TClass : class {
    public TClass Instance;
    public StructOf(TClass instance) => Instance = instance;
    public static implicit operator StructOf<TClass>(TClass s) => new StructOf<TClass>(s);
    public static implicit operator TClass(StructOf<TClass> s) => s.Instance;
    public override string ToString() {
        return this.Instance.ToString();
    }
    // TODO: override Equals, GetHashCode etc., ==, !=
}

Now, your original generic type can be constrained like this:
public class TreeNode<TKey>
where TKey : struct {
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TKey? ParentId { get; set; }
}

So example use would be something like this (made simpler by us having the implicit operator overloaded)
StructOf<string> foo = "foo"; // possible via implicit operator overload
Console.WriteLine(foo); // foo
string bar = foo; // possible via implicit operator overload
Console.WriteLine(bar); // foo

TreeNode<StructOf<string>> treeNode = new();
treeNode.Id = "foo"; // again implicit operator
treeNode.ParentId = null;

TreeNode<Guid> baz = new ();
baz.Id = new Guid();
baz.ParentId = null;

